# Looking for a better solution than a bunch of switch statements in my JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm calling this function from my html (and in some cases from another function in my JavaScript).  These type of `switch` statements are starting to litter my code.  Is there a more elegant solution to these `if` statements?  I wish I could pass a reference to the variables I want to modify.  I'm finally asking the question because now I have a situation where if I do it this same way, I'm going to have an ugly `switch` statement with hundreds of cases which I'm guessing not only looks ugly, but will hurt performance.

```
function incCriteriaStats(exp){
    switch (exp) {
      case "a":
        numOfA++;
        break;
      case "b":
        numOfB++;
        break;
      case "c":
        numOfC++;
        break;
      case "d":
        numOfD++;
        break;
      case "e":
        numOfE++;
        break;
      case "f":
        numOfF++;
        break;
      case "g":
        numOfG++;
        break;    
    }
|
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not use an object to store the values for `a`, `b`, `c`, etc, rather than using separate `numOfA`, `numOfB`, etc variables:

```
var obj = { 
   "a": 0,
   "b": 0,
   "c": 0,
   "d": 0,
   "e": 0,
   "f": 0,
   "g": 0
};
```

This will allow you to do something nice and simple like this:

```
function incCriteriaStats(exp){
   if (obj[exp] != null)
       obj[exp]++;
}
```

Comment: Beat you by just a minute :P

Comment: @Dhaivat ok +1 - I found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8703764/352552) so I guess I'm over it :-)

Answer (score 12):

Use an object, with the keys being the letters, and then you can just do:

```
function incCriteriaStats(exp) {
        if(exp in obj)
             obj[exp]++;
}
```

Comment: Sorry - looks like your slick answer that beat me by a minute was moved to this black hole.  Don't take it too hard, it's happened to me before.

Answer (score 2):

```
var obj={};
function incCriteriaStats(exp) {
    if (typeof(obj[exp]=="undefined") {
        obj[exp]=1;
    } else {
        obj[exp]++;
    }
}
```

The object obj will end up like:

```
{
    "a": 4,
    "b": 5,
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Obj isn't accessible from global scope, you can only get it by calling `incCriteriaStats` which increment key `exp` in `obj` var and return it

```
var incCriteriaStats = (function( ) {
        var obj={}
        return function( exp ) { 
          exp ? obj[ exp ] = ( obj[ exp ] || 0 ) +1 : 0;
          return obj;
        }
     })();

incCriteriaStats( "a" )
incCriteriaStats( "a" )
incCriteriaStats( "a" )[ "a" ] // 3
incCriteriaStats( "a" )[ "a" ] // 4
incCriteriaStats( "b" );

var obj = incCriteriaStats() // get the `obj` from inside incCriteriaStatus without modifying it;
obj.a == 4; //true
obj.b == 1; //true
```